# How to return more than one select queries in same procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I would like to ask how can i print output in procedure more than one statement.
Assume that you want to show dba_objects and segments row count. But i can not use dbms_sql.return_result my version is 11g.

Something like,

```
create or replace procedure get_rows_count
(
  cursor1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,
  cursor2 out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as
begin
    open cursor1 for select count(*) from dba_objects;
    open cursor2 for select count(*) from dba_segments;
end get_rows_count;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assume that you want to show dba_objects and segments row count

I assumed it. Conclusion: that's not the way to do it. If you want to get row count from e.g. `dba_objects`, then you should just

```
select count(*) from dba_objects;
```

in any variation you want (pure SQL, function that returns that number, procedure with an OUT parameter (worse option), ...). But, creating a procedure which uses ref cursor for **that purpose** is ... well, *wrong*.

---

If I got you wrong, then: procedure you wrote is OK. You can call it from another PL/SQL procedure (named or anonymous), fetch result into a variable and *do something* with it (e.g. display it).

Your procedure (selects from Scott's tables; I don't have access to DBA_ views):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_rows_count (cursor1  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  2                                              cursor2  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5     OPEN cursor1 FOR SELECT * FROM emp;
  6
  7     OPEN cursor2 FOR SELECT * FROM dept;
  8  END get_rows_count;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

How to call it? See line #8:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     rc1  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     rc2  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  4     --
  5     rw1  emp%ROWTYPE;
  6     rw2  dept%ROWTYPE;
  7  BEGIN
  8     get_rows_count (rc1, rc2);
  9
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Employees -----------');
 11
 12     LOOP
 13        FETCH rc1 INTO rw1;
 14
 15        EXIT WHEN rc1%NOTFOUND;
 16
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rw1.ename);
 18     END LOOP;
 19
 20     --
 21     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Departments ---------');
 22
 23     LOOP
 24        FETCH rc2 INTO rw2;
 25
 26        EXIT WHEN rc2%NOTFOUND;
 27
 28        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rw2.dname);
 29     END LOOP;
 30
 31     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('First ref cursor: ' || rc1%ROWCOUNT);
 32     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Second ref cursor: ' || rc2%ROWCOUNT);
 33  END;
 34  /
```

Result:

```
Employees -----------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER
Departments ---------
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS
First ref cursor: 14
Second ref cursor: 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: you are right i forgot to type count(*) thanks i will try your block to.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` should perform WAY BETTER than any kind of loop (and, if you work with cursors, you have to loop; there's no way to find out how many rows it returns until you reach the end). If cursor returns small number of rows, you won't notice any difference, but DBA_OBJECTS can be large so it'll take time to find out that simple information - number of rows within. SELECT COUNT(*) is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for detail information. I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use famous `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` along with `%ROWCOUNT` suffix for your case such as

```
SET serveroutput ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_rows_count(
                                            cursor1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                            cursor2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                            count1  OUT INT,
                                            count2  OUT INT
                                          ) AS
  cur_rec_obj user_objects%ROWTYPE;
  cur_rec_seg user_segments%ROWTYPE;      
BEGIN
    OPEN cursor1 FOR SELECT * FROM user_objects;
    LOOP
      FETCH cursor1 INTO cur_rec_obj;  
      EXIT WHEN cursor1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    OPEN cursor2 FOR SELECT * FROM user_segments;
    LOOP
      FETCH cursor2 INTO cur_rec_seg;  
      EXIT WHEN cursor2%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;

    count1 := cursor1%ROWCOUNT;
    count2 := cursor2%ROWCOUNT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(count1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(count2);    
      
END;
/
```

and you can call as follows from the SQL Window of PL/SQL Developer :

```
DECLARE
 v_cursor1   SYS_REFCURSOR;
 v_cursor2   SYS_REFCURSOR;
 v_count1    INT;
 v_count2    INT;
BEGIN
  get_rows_count(v_cursor1, v_cursor2, v_count1, v_count2 );
END;
/
```

Comment: When i call proc i am getting below error did i miss something?                                   
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ROWS_COUNT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: How do you call the procedure @microracle . Btw, I've just added two new out parameters as well to represent those counts.

Comment: I have tried many ways to call. Can you help to me about how should i call?

Comment: by the way i am very sorry for your lost on earthquake :((

Comment: Thank you very much @microracle , I appreciated. Unfortunately it's really devastating ... Btw, edited the answer. Take care.